# Placing TextView above custom View programatically in Relative Layout

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to programatically position a TextView above a custom View in a Relative Layout that has also been placed programatically (lets call this CustomView).

I've scoured these forums for similar problems, and I seem to have done all the steps, including setting ids, making sure there are no conflicting rules, etc. But yet it doesn't seem to work.

I am wondering if this has to do with the fact that my CustomView class overrides the onDraw() method (it needs to eventually be animated). In fact, testing the CustomView with it's own set of LayoutParams shows that it does not obey the rules laid out in it - in fact the way that I place this CustomView is by calling canvas.drawBitmap() with the relevant positions in the onDraw() method of CustomView.

Any idea how I can get around this problem? Is it possible to somehow place the the TextView above the CustomView?

Comment: You forgot to post the relevant code

Comment: I think your should post your xml.  A picture of what's happening and what you want would be helpful as well.